# Cannot catch HttpMessageNotReadableException into ControllerAdvice for enums validation

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums

I have a Enum class as follow:

```
public enum UserRole {
    ADMIN("ADMIN"),
    USER ("USER");


    public String label;

    UserRole(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getValue() {
        return this.label;
    }
}
```

My DTO uses as follow:

```
@EnumValidator(enumClass = UserRole.class, message = "Invalid Role")
UserRole role
```

My custom Validators:

```
public class EnumValidatorConstraint implements ConstraintValidator<EnumValidator, String> {



    private static final Set<String> TYPE_NAMES =
            EnumSet.allOf(UserRole.class).stream().map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String engineType,
                           ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

        if (!TYPE_NAMES.contains(engineType)) throw new UserNotExistsException(engineType);

        return true;
    }
}
```

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE, TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy= EnumValidatorConstraint.class)
@Documented
public @interface EnumValidator {
    Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass();
    String message() default "must be any of enum {enumClass}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

I can see at log this message when submitting a enum that doesnot belongs to the enum and at my request response:

```
2023-09-28T11:13:33.498-03:00  WARN 10995 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.gustavomr.domain.UserRole` from String "XXXX": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [USER, ADMIN]]
```

```
{
    "type": "about:blank",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "Failed to read request",
    "instance": "/user/register"
}
```

I have a controller advice that handles all excpetions in order to format:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler  extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseDTO> handle(HttpMessageNotReadableException exception,
                                                                  WebRequest webRequest) {
        ErrorResponseDTO errorResponseDTO = new ErrorResponseDTO(
                webRequest.getDescription(false),
                HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                exception.getMessage(),
                LocalDateTime.now()
        );
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponseDTO, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

My @Controller advice is not capturing the exception captured by enum validator. I've testes using @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) but didn't work as well.

I tried to use at method level @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class) but also gives me a error about ambiguity during spring boot startup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override this method in ControllerAdvice

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(
        HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, 
        HttpHeaders headers, 
        HttpStatusCode status, 
        WebRequest request
) {
    ErrorResponseDTO errorResponseDTO = new ErrorResponseDTO(
            webRequest.getDescription(false),
            HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            exception.getMessage(),
            LocalDateTime.now()
    );
    return super.handleExceptionInternal(ex, errorResponseDTO, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request);
}
```